# Filter for remote server response from netcat SMTP scan

Tags: bash, shell-script, netcat

I am using netcat to test if remote exchange server (lets call it exchange1) is online with this code.

```
nc -w 3 192.168.130.17 25
```

I want to create a file that has that servers name if and only if the netcat scan receives a response of **'220 SMTP Server Ready'**, meaning exchange1 is online. If there is no response, I don't want to write the name to the file because it is offline.

1. What is this called. I believe it to be a type of command result filtering but having trouble finding any articles about how its done.
2. Can someone provide a simple example of this so I can learn from it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `grep` to check of the output of some command matches a pattern, by piping the output of that other command to `grep`. You use `grep` inside an `if` block.

An obviously silly example (and the whole world calls it "Friday", right?):

```shell
if date +%A | grep -q 'Friday'; then   # -q tells grep not to echo the matched text
    throw_a_party
else
    echo "Nope, sorry, not time yet."
fi
```

The relevant sections of the Bash manual include "Pipelines" and "Compound Commands".

Comment: @CaseyMcCarthy There is a checkmark next to the answer you can click to say it solved your problem. You might want to look at the [tour](http://unix.stackexchange.com/tour) for a quick overview of how the site works.

Comment: Just selected the check, thanks I'll check it out!